# How to remove space from CLOBs in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problems with removing space from CLOB column in Oracle. I have tried to use the CLOB format and trim in SQL but the space is still there. My field is using string text. I don't want space in text. Anyone knows how to fix this?

This is my SQL:

```
select distinct
  UPPER(ks.NAMA) BPMNAMA,
  trim(upper(nvl(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ks.sekatan, 4000, 1),'TIADA'))) sekatnama,
  UPPER(ks.NAMA) DAERAHNAMA,
  UPPER(ks.nama) gunatanah
from
  guna_tanah ks
```

For example:

### sekatnama

TANAH INI TIDAK BOLEH DI PINDAHMILIK, DISEWA ATAU DIPAJAK

KECUALI DENGAN KEBENARAN PIHAK BERKUASA NEGERI. SEKATAN

KEPENTINGAN INI DIKECUALIKAN KEPADA PEMBELI PERTAMA.

How to remove the space eventhough i put the trim?

Answer (score 1):

use `regexp_replace(ks.sekatan, '[[:space:]]',null)`

please refer this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm

...
...However, the following statement is not supported because DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR returns a LOB:

CREATE TABLE tab AS SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(clob_col) from tab@dbs2;

...

You cannot specify LOB columns in the ORDER BY clause of a query, or in the GROUP BY clause of a query or in an aggregate function.

You cannot specify a LOB column in a SELECT... DISTINCT or SELECT... UNIQUE statement or in a join. However, you can specify a LOB attribute of an object type column in a SELECT... DISTINCT statement or in a query that uses the UNION or MINUS set operator if the column's object type has a MAP or ORDER function defined on it.
..
(hope these helps).. thanks